# Tkinter Global Variable Errors

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global-variables

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'userScore' referenced before assignment

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'comScore' referenced before assignment

I have tried declaring them as a global variable as well as passing them as parameters (works but resets the score each time). Here's my code:

```
userScore = 0
comScore = 0
options = [[comRock, 'Rock'], [comPaper, 'Paper'], [comScissors, 'Scissors']]

# def start():
#    startFrame.pack_forget()
#    visualFrame.pack()
#    controlFrame.pack()


def play(img, userIn):
    comIn = random.choice(options)
    Label(visualFrame, image=img, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=0)
    Label(visualFrame, image=comIn[0], borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=2)
    Label(visualFrame, image=vsImg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=1)

    if userIn == comIn[1]:
        Label(visualFrame, image=tieImg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    elif (userIn == "Rock" and comIn[1] == "Scissors") or (userIn == "Scissors" and comIn[1] == "Paper") \
            or (userIn == "Paper" and comIn[1] == "Rock"):
        Label(visualFrame, image=wonImg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
        userScore += 1
    else:
        Label(visualFrame, image=lostImg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
        comScore += 1

    Label(visualFrame, text=str(userScore) + ':' + str(comScore)).place(x=295, y=205)
```

Comment: You need to declare `userScore` as global inside `play()` by adding `global userScore` at the beginning of `play()`. Same applies on `comScore` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `userScore` global just after the function definition

```
def play(img, userIn):
    global userScore
    ...
```